# How to remove underscore and capitalize the next character in the first word?

Tags: vimscript, string-manipulation

I want to modify the first word of each line: remove underscore character and capitalize the next character.

#### Input:

```
   word_example_one other_words ...   
   word_example_two other_words ...   
   word_example_three other_words ...
```

#### Expected output:

```
   wordExampleOne other_words ...  
   wordExampleTwo other_words ...  
   wordExampleThree other_words ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try substitute with `:h sub-replace-special`:

```
:%s/^\w\+/\=substitute(submatch(0), '_\(\a\)', '\u\1', 'g')
```

with `:%s/^\w\+/` you target first word, then with special replace, you substitute within whole match (first word in our case), using `:h substitute()` function.

Thus, having text like:

```
word_example_one ...  word_example_one ...
word_example_two ...  word_example_two ...
word_example_three ...  word_example_three ...
```

and running this command, you get:

```
wordExampleOne ...  word_example_one ...
wordExampleTwo ...  word_example_two ...
wordExampleThree ...  word_example_three ...
```

Comment: Sometimes there are leading spaces at the start of each line.

Comment: add `\s*` to the regex...

Comment: `%s/^\s*\w\+/\=substitute(submatch(0), '_\(\a\)', '\u\1', 'g')`

Comment: Add another solution to the answer?
Visual select the words then `:'<,'>s:\%V\v_(.):\U\1:g`.

Comment: it wouldn't work for all cases -- words might be different length and you might not be able to select those words without selecting unneeded (non-first). So you might replace not what you wanted. https://i.imgur.com/ee6y7rM.png

Answer (score 1):

Another `:substitute`-based option, where the pattern is simpler:

```
:substitute/\v_(\a)/\u\1
```

and then use `&` to repeat this on the line until you are satisfied (it only changes the first `_` in the line each time). If you want to repeat this across the whole file, use `:%substitute` first and then type `g&` as many times as necessary.

---

With [tpope's vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish), `crc` coerces to `camelCase`. So you could do (for example)

```
:[range]normal ^crc
```

to change the first word on the lines covered by `[range]` to camel case.

Comment: `:substitute/\v_(\a)/\u\1` will replace all `_\a`. OP wants to replace only in the first word. (I answered this solution and deleted upon OP's clarification. And I'm jealous of your 1 upvote. xD)

Comment: @kadekai not so: the `g` flag is missing, so the substitute only happens for the first occurence in the line(s) covered by the range (default current line). Hence the need to press `&` to continue until the word is changed; it’s more work, but I find the pattern and replacement easier to type

Comment: That makes sense. Specially if you use macros. I myself would do it that way.